# jQuery script not working w/ Bootstrap + Addons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and another addon called "Get Shit Done". 
http://demos.creative-tim.com/get-shit-done/components.html

I'm having this weird issue where my jQuery doesn't want to work with them and I'm even using one of their preset pieces of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(':checkbox1').on('toggle', function() {
    $("texty").text("Hello, you have clicked me!"); 
});
</script>
```

However, when I do this, it fails to change anything. It might be due to the formatting or "checkbox 1" but I'm pretty sure thats where the id of the checkbox goes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your selectors are not correct.

If your checkbox id is "checkbox1" then the selector should be "#checkbox1". I'm not sure what a "texty" element is, but if that is an id of some element, the selector should be "#texty".

Comment: Thanks! so essentially like $(':#checkbox1').on('toggle', function() {
    $("#texty").text("Hello, you have clicked me!"); ?

Comment: Get rid of the ":" on the first selector. $("#checkbox1") and $("#texty")

Comment: Also, texty is a <p> element.

Comment: Yeah, since you didn't post any of the html, I'm just making guesses for the selector you need. See https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp for jquery selector help.

Comment: Ok awesome! Thanks for the help, works like a charm.